# Get attribute from laravel's "with" closure

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have something like that:

```
$order = Order::with('user')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

It returns:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "price": null,
        "user": {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "jon"
         }
    }
```

Now inside my laravel code I want to get id of user. How is that possible? 
because `$order->user` returns just `null`

Comment: Can you show the schema and models for both order and user?

Comment: To be honest that's just simplified example. I can't show whole model. You have some clue? what may be causing that?

Comment: Either the relationship is set up incorrectly, or the user does not exist for that order. `$order->user->id` should return the id of the user related to the order, unless an order has many users.

Comment: Can you show the relationship in order and user model please?

Comment: `$order->user->id` should return the `id`, given that the order has a user

Comment: relationship is correct, because I get correct json (including user). but I just can't catch user inside php code. $order has user but I can't write `$order->user`

Comment: We will need to see how/where you are trying to access it.

Comment: "_because I get correct json (including user)_" But that JSON only contains the keys (`id`, `name`) and no values.

Comment: sorry that's my mistake, I wrote json incorrectly in question. I'll edit it

Comment: I return `$order` in postman, and it has user property, but when I return `$order->user` , it's `null`

Comment: Can you provide the whole function that you are using to access the `$order->user`? It's impossible to troubleshoot one line answers to all of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since above value returned by Order::with('user')->where('id', $id)->first(); is a collection so try chaining the result with pluck like below

```
Order::with('user')->where('id', $id)->first()->pluck(user.id);
```

Let me know if this works for you as I could not replicate it on my machine.